# Code isn't compatible with IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = document.location.toString();
    $('.tab').click(function() {
        if($(this).is(".active")) {
            return;
        }

        var classy = $(this).attr("class").split(" ").splice(-1);
        var innerhtml = $('.content.'+classy).text();
        $('#holder').html(innerhtml);
        $('.tab').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });

    var url = document.location.toString();

    if(url.match(/#([a-z])/)) {
        //There is a hash, followed by letters in it, therefore the user is targetting a page.  
        var split = url.split("#").splice(-1);
        $('.tab.'+split).click();
    }
    else {
        $('.tab:first').click();
    }
});
```

Hey, I was just informed by one of my commenters that this code doesn't work in IE. I can't for the life of me figure out why. Whenever you switch tabs, the content of the tab doesn't change. Meanwhile the content of the #holder div is all the tabs combined.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did they say which version of IE they were using?  IE6 is riddled with problems that have mostly been fixed in IE7/8.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I'd try it in IE8 first.  If it works there, then press F12 to get the developer console up, then click the broken page icon next to the address bar to put it into IE6/7 compatibility mode.  This will reload the page, and any errors your code causes will appear in the developer console.

If it still works, only then will you have to seek out a genuine IE6 machine.

Comment: Hey, this still isn't working. The link to the code is in a comment below. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did all changes which Ryan suggested except adding the space between '.content' and the period as it is needed. He could not have known without the source code.

I changed your .splice(-1) to [1] so that I'm choosing the second item in the array, which is the class name. It looks like .splice(-1) is behaving differently in IE and other browsers.

I have tested the code with IE 7-8 and it works.

Source code as it is now:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = document.location.hash;

    $('.tab').click(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
            return;
        }

        var classy = $(this).attr("class").split(" ")[1];
        var innerhtml = $('.content.' + classy).text();

        $('#holder').html(innerhtml).slideDown("slow");

        $('.tab').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });

    if (url.match(/#([a-z])/)) {
        //There is a hash, followed by letters in it, therefore the user is targetting a page.  
        var split = url.split("#")[1];
        $('.tab.' + split).click();
    }
    else {
        $('.tab:first').click();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Not the answer you're after, but I'd [seriously recommend](http://net.tutsplus.com/javascript-ajax/create-a-tabbed-interface-using-jquery/) looking into the [jQueryui tabs widget](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs) if you can. It's made my life *a lot* easier dealing with this stuff at least.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell without an IE version and a page to look at what exactly is happening- but here are some best guesses:

change:

```
if($(this).is(".active")) {
```

to:

```
if($(this).hasClass("active")) {
```

change:

```
var innerhtml = $('.content.'+classy).text();
```

to:

```
var innerhtml = $('.content .'+classy).text(); // note the space
```

change:

```
var url = document.location.toString();
```

to:

```
var url = document.location.hash;
```

Comment: and don't test for "url.match", as the hashmark won't be included- just see if it exists

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply, here's the link to the code:
http://www.webtint.net/filebank/jquery/tabswitcher/

Comment: sorry bout the wait- had to do some of the work i get paid for... Manticore seems to have done the work below